# Object.freeze / Object.seal in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is `Object.freeze` suggested in Typescript or is there other way of making sure object remains immutable?

Since `const` only guards instance, but not properties, this is obviously not an answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/substack/deep-freeze?

Comment: `Object.freeze` is a runtime concept. TypeScript just runs on JavaScript, so...

Comment: @DanielA.White, naturally I am talking about compile-time checks without having Object.freeze allover my code

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> is there other way of making sure object remains immutable?

It depends on the level of insurance that you want to have.

If you want to make sure that no consumer, be it TypeScript or JavaScript code, could modify object properties at runtime, `Object.freeze` is the way to do it.

If compile-time checks are sufficient, for example when all consumer code is guaranteed to be TypeScript-only and typechecked, you can use  [`ReadOnly` generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#partial-readonly-record-and-pick), which takes an object type and makes all [properties `readonly`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#readonly-properties). In fact, `Object.freeze()` is declared in [library type definitions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L201) as returning `ReadOnly`-modified type of its argument:

```
freeze<T>(o: T): Readonly<T>;
```

For `seal`, there is no way to represent sealed object in the type system, `Object.seal()` is [declared to return the same type it receives](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L183):

```
seal<T>(o: T): T;
```

and `Object.seal()` is the only way to go.

Comment: Actual Typescript's typing system contains "interfaces" which automatically enforce everything Object.seal does. Typically there use in predefined types also enforces typing on the attributes they contain something Object.seal doesn't do.

Answer (score 20):

### Simplest Solution: `as const`

This represents a deep freeze of immutability through all levels of objects or arrays.

```
const a = {
    b: 1,
    c: {d: 'e'},
    f: ['g', 'h'],
} as const
```

None of these will allow overwriting

```
a = 'not'
a.b = 'going'
a.c.d = 'to'
a.f[1] = 'change'

All result in error "TS2540: Cannot assign to '<name>' because it is a read-only property."
```

> NOTE: Custom objects may not be fully immutable, depending on your implementation.

**Bonus**: If using as an enum replacement, you can add this line

```
type a = typeof a[keyof typeof a]
```

### Immutable Parameter with `Immutable<>`

This does the same thing as `as const` to deep freeze a parameter

```
// Add this and make it reuseable
type Immutable<T> = {
    readonly [K in keyof T]: Immutable<T[K]>
}
```

Define type within `<>`, i.e. `Immutable<MyType>`

```
_method = (a: Immutable<{b:{c:{d:[string]}}}>) => {
    // This will complain
    a.b.c.d[0] = ""
}
```

[Official Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html)

Answer (score 3):

If you want runtime and compile time checks you could do,

```
export const frozen:Readonly<{a:number}> = Object.freeze({a:1});
```

however the following, already gives me a TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property

```
export const frozen = Object.freeze({a:1});
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursively Object.freeze() on objects and functions adding readonly type:

```
export const deepFreeze = <T>(source: T, freezeParent = true): DRo<T> => {
  if (freezeParent) Object.freeze(source)

  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(source).forEach(function(prop) {
    if (
      Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(source as any, prop) &&
      (source as any)[prop] !== null &&
      (typeof (source as any)[prop] === 'object' || typeof (source as any)[prop] === 'function')
    ) {
      if (Object.isFrozen((source as any)[prop])) {
        deepFreeze((source as any)[prop], false)
      } else {
        deepFreeze((source as any)[prop], true)
      }
    }
  })

  return source as DRo<T>
}

type DRo<T> = T extends (infer R)[] ? DRoArr<R> : T extends Function ? T : T extends object ? DRoObj<T> : T

interface DRoArr<T> extends ReadonlyArray<DRo<T>> {}

type DRoObj<T> = {
  readonly [P in keyof T]: DRo<T[P]>
}
```

Object.freeze includes Seal.