# How to use enum as props in react/typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enums

I have the following enum

```
export enum Sizes{
    Small,
    Large
}
```

which is getting used in my `<Demo/>` component's props interface:

```
export interface IProps{
    Label?: string;
    Size: SizeEnum;
}
```

My question is, when I use this `<Demo Size={how do i define size here?} />`?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can just reference the enum value as you would in any other context:

```
export enum Sizes{
    Small,
    Large
}

export interface IProps{
    Label?: string;
    Size: Sizes;
}

class Demo extends React.Component<IProps> {}

let d = <Demo Size={Sizes.Large} />
```

Comment: do i need to redefine the enum again in the Component that's rendering `Demo`?

Comment: No, you should be able to import from the module where you defined it as you would any other type

Comment: so something like `import { Demo, Sizes} from "../src/Demo.tsx";` ?

Comment: but when i do `SizeEnum.Small` i dont get intellisense for small or large

Comment: I do, what is the name of your enum ? `Size` or  `SizeEnum` ? you seem to use both, you should the defined enum name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168611/discussion-between-titian-cernicova-dragomir-and-zerodarkthirty).

Comment: it works if you get rid of the `tsx` from `import { Demo, Sizes} from "../src/Demo.tsx`

Comment: how to use Size defined in IProps inside Demo?

Answer (score 26):

### Use `type` or `as const`

Both `type` and `as const` have auto-fill and will complain when an invalid value is used.

#### type

```
'up'
```

Implement with:

```
type MyEnum = 'up' | 'down' | 'left' | 'right'

interface IProps {
  Size: MyEnum
}
```

#### as const

```
MyEnum.Up
```

Implement with:

```
const MyEnum = {
  Up: 'up',
  Down: 'down',
  Left: 'left',
  Right: 'right',
} as const

type MyEnum = typeof MyEnum[keyof typeof MyEnum]

// Example type
interface IProps {
  Size: MyEnum // string, without line `type MyEnum =...`
}
```

[More detail on `as const` and freezing parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63620451/974045)

Comment: Would be great with reference to the statement "... considered a bad and unreliable practice in typescript"?